# Issues using flask cached session out from context (spotipy authentication)

Tags: python, authentication, flask, session, spotipy

I encounter issues with Spotipy Authentication over Flask when trying to access stored session outside flask context.
My python app is running outside the webserver and needs some remaining authentication to work properly : my existing flask api seemed to be the best way to do this correctly.

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect
from flask_session import Session
import spotipy, os

os.environ['SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI'] = "http://localhost:6681/api/spotipy_init"
os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID'] = "xxx"
os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET'] = "xxx"

def create_api():
        api = Flask(__name__)
        api.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(64)
        api.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
        api.config['SESSION_FILE_DIR'] = './.flask_session/'
        Session(api)
        return api

api=create_api()
api.app_context().push()

#Part 1 : sp authentication
@api.route('/api/spotipy_init')
def api_spotipy_init():
    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(scope='user-read-currently-playing playlist-modify-private',cache_handler=cache_handler,show_dialog=True)

    if request.args.get("code"):
        # Step 2. Being redirected from Spotify auth page
        auth_manager.get_access_token(request.args.get("code"))
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
        return redirect('/api/spotipy_init')

    if not auth_manager.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        # Step 1. Display sign in link when no token
        auth_url = auth_manager.get_authorize_url()
        return f'<h2><a href="{auth_url}">Sign in</a></h2>'

    # Step 3. Signed in, display data
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
    return f'<h2>Hi {sp.me()["display_name"]}, ' \
    f'<small><a href="/api/spotipy_out">[sign out]<a/></small></h2>' \

#Part 2 : using authentication outside from flask
with api.app_context():
    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(cache_handler=cache_handler)

    if auth_manager.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
        print (sp.me()["display_name"])
```

Authentication in Part 1 works fine, but error appears in Part2 when trying to access it in main app context (sp.me...) :

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
> an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
> information about how to avoid this problem.

Perhaps my try to use with api.context() is not done the right way : thanks for your help.